# Show that the determinant is equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, complex-numbers, contest-math, determinant

> Problem: Show that the following equation is true,$$ \begin{vmatrix}
>  \frac{(a+b+c+d)(bcd+acd+abd+abc)}{4abcd} && \frac{a+b+c+d}{2} &&
>  \frac{bcd+acd+abd+abc}{2abcd} && 1 \\  \frac{( ab(c+d)-c
>  d(a+b))(a+b-c-d)}{(a b-c d)^2} && \frac{a b(c+d)-c d(a+b)}{a b-c d} &&
>  \frac{a+b-c-d}{ab-cd} && 1 \\  \frac{(a d(c+b)-c b(a+d))(a+d-c-b)}{(a
>  d-c b)^2} && \frac{a d(c+b)-c b(a+d)}{a d-c b} && \frac{a+d-c-b}{ad-cb}
>  && 1 \\  \frac{(a c(b+d)-b d(a+c))(a+c-b-d)}{(a c-b d)^2} && \frac{a
>  c(b+d)-b d(a+c)}{a c-b d} && \frac{a+c-b-d}{ac-bd} && 1  \notag
>  \end{vmatrix}=0 $$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$.
> What is the simplest way of establishing this result?

### Context

In one of my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4163016/property-of-the-anticenter-of-a-cyclic-quadrilateral/4163784#4163784)s, I used Mathematica to check a result. At first I was being lazy, but then I noticed that the equation was not easy to verify. It got me wondering whether it is possible to evaluate such an equation under contest conditions.

I was trying to show that the complex numbers $t, f, e, x$ are concyclic. I had defined them as follows ($e$ was obtained by swapping $b$'s and $d$'s in $f$ and $x$ was obtained by swapping $b$'s and $c$'s in $f$)
$$t=\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}$$
$$f=\frac{a b(c+d)-c d(a+b)}{a b-c d}$$
$$
e=\frac{a d(c+b)-c b(a+d)}{a d-c b}$$
$$ x=\frac{a c(b+d)-b d(a+c)}{a c-b d}
$$
with $a,b,c,d \;$ being complex numbers which lie on the unit circle. In my answer, I verified the following (concylic criterion) using Mathematica,

$$\frac{f-t}{e-t} \div \frac{f-x}{e-x} \; \in \; \mathbb{R} \tag{1}$$

but this equation is hard to verify by hand (though, it may still be easier than what I tried next).

There is another criterion to check whether the points lie on a circle, involving a $4 \; x\;4$ determinant. It can be shown that the four complex numbers $z_{1}, z_{2}, z_{3}, z_{4}$ lie on a generalized circle iff:
$$\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
z_{1} \overline{z_{1}} & z_{1} & \overline{z_{1}} & 1 \\
z_{2} \overline{z_{2}} & z_{2} & \overline{z_{2}} & 1 \\
z_{3} \overline{z_{3}} & z_{3} & \overline{z_{3}} & 1 \\
z_{4} \overline{z_{4}} & z_{4} & \overline{z_{4}} & 1
\end{array}\right|=0
$$

Therefore, we are trying to show that

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\dfrac{a+b+c+d}{2}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{d}}{2} & \dfrac{a+b+c+d}{2} & \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{d}}{2} && 1 \\ 
\dfrac{a b(c+d)-c d(a+b)}{a b-c d}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{1}{b}(\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{d})-\dfrac{1}{c} \dfrac{1}{d}(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b})}{\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{1}{b}-\dfrac{1}{c} \dfrac{1}{d}} & \dfrac{a b(c+d)-c d(a+b)}{a b-c d} & \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{1}{b}(\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{d})-\dfrac{1}{c} \dfrac{1}{d}(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b})}{\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{1}{b}-\dfrac{1}{c} \dfrac{1}{d}} && 1 \\ 
\dfrac{a d(c+b)-c b(a+d)}{a d-c b}\cdot \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{1}{d}(\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{b})-\dfrac{1}{c} \dfrac{1}{b}(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{d})}{\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{1}{d}-\dfrac{1}{c} \dfrac{1}{b}} & \dfrac{a d(c+b)-c b(a+d)}{a d-c b} & \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{1}{d}(\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{1}{b})-\dfrac{1}{c} \dfrac{1}{b}(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{d})}{\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{1}{d}-\dfrac{1}{c} \dfrac{1}{b}} && 1 \\ 
\dfrac{a c(b+d)-b d(a+c)}{a c-b d}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{1}{c}(\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{d})-\dfrac{1}{b} \dfrac{1}{d}(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{c})}{\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{1}{c}-\dfrac{1}{b} \dfrac{1}{d}} & \dfrac{a c(b+d)-b d(a+c)}{a c-b d} & \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{1}{c}(\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{d})-\dfrac{1}{b} \dfrac{1}{d}(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{c})}{\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{1}{c}-\dfrac{1}{b} \dfrac{1}{d}} && 1  \notag
\end{vmatrix}
$$
is equal to zero. Simplifying the expressions:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\dfrac{(a+b+c+d)(bcd+acd+abd+abc)}{4abcd} & \dfrac{a+b+c+d}{2} & \dfrac{bcd+acd+abd+abc}{2abcd} & 1 \\ 
\dfrac{( ab(c+d)-c d(a+b))(a+b-c-d)}{(a b-c d)^2} & \dfrac{a b(c+d)-c d(a+b)}{a b-c d} & \dfrac{a+b-c-d}{ab-cd} & 1 \\ 
\dfrac{(a d(c+b)-c b(a+d))(a+d-c-b)}{(a d-c b)^2} & \dfrac{a d(c+b)-c b(a+d)}{a d-c b} & \dfrac{a+d-c-b}{ad-cb} & 1 \\ 
\dfrac{(a c(b+d)-b d(a+c))(a+c-b-d)}{(a c-b d)^2} & \dfrac{a c(b+d)-b d(a+c)}{a c-b d} & \dfrac{a+c-b-d}{ac-bd} & 1  \notag
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Since we are trying to show that the determinant is (a multiple of) zero, we are free to multiply rows and columns with arbitrary constants. I decided to get rid of the denominators

\begin{align*}
\small
\begin{vmatrix}
(a+b+c+d)(bcd+acd+abd+abc) & (a+b+c+d)(2abcd) & {2(bcd+acd+abd+abc)} & 4abcd \\ 
( ab(c+d)-c d(a+b))(a+b-c-d) & (a b(c+d)-c d(a+b))(a b-c d) & (a+b-c-d)(a b-c d) & (a b-c d)^2 \\ 
(a d(c+b)-c b(a+d))(a+d-c-b) & (a d(c+b)-c b(a+d))(a d-c b) & (a+d-c-b)(ad-cb) & (a d-c b)^2 \\ 
(a c(b+d)-b d(a+c))(a+c-b-d) & (a c(b+d)-b d(a+c))(a c-b d) & (a+c-b-d)(ac-bd) & (a c-b d)^2  \notag
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}

which resulted in another ugly-looking determinant. I hope a clever manipulation of the determinant exists (leading to a cyclic sum or something significantly simpler).

What is the easiest way to evaluate this determinant under contest conditions, or is my inital criterion, Equation $(1)$, more straightforward to verify?

Thank you in advance.